# Interpreting IRF graph

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I am new to using VAR model. I have an orthogonal IRF that shows the temperature shock to tourist accommodation demand.

[image: temperature shock to motel demand]

Ideal irf graph shows that the effect of shock dies out after sometime, but my graph shows an oscillating effect. How do I interpret the graph?

Thank You

Comment: There is only one period at which demand is significantly shocked by temperature, that period being time unit 1.